# reverse() method in array javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, developer-tools

I have a little bit of confusion actually may Someone please clear me out, The thing is that in my code I have an array with 10 elements, I want to reverse the elements but from 3-8 position, not whole array elements, is it possible I tried by indexing but failed to have another option please show me here the solution.

Comment: You can use something like this `[].concat(array.slice(0,3), array.slice(3,8).reverse(), array.slice(8))`

Comment: array.splice(2, 0, ...array.splice(2, 8).reverse())

Answer (score 1):

The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array. Also this function doesn't have any argument. In addition I suggest a solution for you blow :

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var result = customReverse(nums, 2, 8)

function customReverse(arr, start, end)
{
    let startArr = arr.splice(0,start);
    let endArr = arr.splice(end-start, arr.length-1);
    return startArr.concat(arr.reverse()).concat(endArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of way that you can achieve this. But you can simply follow the below code. I think it's the simplest solution.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var slicedArr = arr.slice(3, 8).reverse();

arr = arr.slice(0,3);
arr.push(...slicedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

As for your question, this can be achieved using [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [Reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
let original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let modified = original.slice(0, 2).concat(original.slice(2).reverse());
console.log({ original, modified });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create another array and put the index values of 3-8. Now reverse it and put it again to the old array.

```
var stack = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var temp_stack = stack.splice(3,5); // start from 3 count next 5 indexes.

temp_stack.reverse(); // This will reverse the values.

// This line again put the reversed array into old array.
stack.splice.apply(stack, [3, 0].concat(temp_stack)); 

// Now the "stack" will be [ 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 10 ]
```